# Spring URI patterns. Using slashes inside regex path

Tags: java, regex, spring, uri

I want to create enpoint with dynamic uri using regex in uri pattern.

URI template: **[host]/{regexpart}/endpoint**

Examples of dynamic uri:

- [host]/a/endpoint
- [host]/b/endpoint

Also I want to use slashes inside regex part of uri path, like that:

- [host]/a/b/endpoint
- [host]/a/b/c/d/endpoint

I have enpoint like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{regexpart:[a-z/]*}/endpoint")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> enpoint(@PathVariable("regexpart") String regexpart) {
    // Some logic 
}
```

But it isn't working. Is there way to define the regex to use slashes inside it? Thanks!

Comment: Escaping it? `[a-z\/]`?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written, the regex pattern is limited to be within 1 path segment.

What you may be looking for is something like

`@GetMapping(path = "/**/endpoint")`

the `**` will allow for any characters across multiple path segments.

This will allow any valid path within your [host] that ends in `/endpoint`
If you need to limit that to certain characters (like just `[a-z]`, this should get you on the right track.